# How to make a hover preview of a flv video?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I'm developing a site that hosts videos; I do have ffmpeg installed and functional. I know how to extract a single frame from the video to use as a display image, but I need to find a way for when someone hovers over the video, it will flip through a few frames. I've been searching for days for a solution but nothing seems to work. Any help?

Comment: Repeat the process to get say 10 frames spanning the whole video, then use javascript to flash through them on hover.

Comment: That's what I was thinking I'd have to do, but I don't know how to write java. I could understand it though if you could post an example.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to go about this. I don't really understand if you are referring to a preview in the player or a preview on the thumbnail; I am going to assume the latter (but logic remains the same in any case).
Once you have extracted your frames from your movies, then the hardest part is done. What you can do now:

1. on hover, make the thumbnail load "imagename+n" until it hits a 404 (or you can hard-encode the number of frames to load)
2. automatically generate gifs out of your frames, and on hover, swap a static image with the gif
3. If it is a player we are talking about, then you can use the same logic as #1: make it load every frame sequentially.

I quickly [fiddled something](http://jsfiddle.net/xananax/ySSGG/).
This example below is in pseudo-code that explains the fiddle

html

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <div class="image">
    <img src="something" class="loaded"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.thumbnail')
    .on('mouseenter',function(){next($(this));})
    .on('mouseleave',function(){stop($(this));})

function next(){
   start timer
   on time, go to next thumbnail
   does it exist? then swap current thumbnail with next thumbnail and stop;
   does it not? check number of thumbnails loaded
     is it equal to 6? then we reached the end, loop back to start and stop;
     is it not? then add the new thumb and begin loading it
        while doing that, loop back to start;
}

function stop(){stop the timer}
```

It's not very elegant and will definitely not work for multiple thumbnails (you'll have problems if you don't store the variables locally for every thumbnail, either with their data-attribute or by using closures), but it gives an idea.

Comment: Yea I understand that concept, taking x amount of frames and swapping with java, but if you could post examples that'd be amazing!

Comment: Added fiddle and more thorough explanation, using jquery